# Customised XLOOKUP formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, vlookup, xlookup

I am trying to Automate an Sheet with an customized xlookup. I am able to figure it out 80% but stuck with the last step. Can any one help?

I have this Formula which I am trying to build using the column headers to automate some xlookups.

```
=XLOOKUP(C2,'IMPORT BASE'!A:A,CONCAT("'",TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(CELL("address",INDEX('IMPORT BASE'!$A$1:$DT$1,MATCH(AY1,'IMPORT BASE'!$A$1:$DT$1,0))),"]"),"$"),TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(CELL("address",INDEX('IMPORT BASE'!$A$1:$DT$1,MATCH(AY1,'IMPORT BASE'!$A$1:$DT$1,0))),"]"),"$",2),"$"),":"&TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(CELL("address",INDEX('IMPORT BASE'!$A$1:$DT$1,MATCH(AY1,'IMPORT BASE'!$A$1:$DT$1,0))),"]"),"$",2),"$")))
```

Where it should create an Formula like this `=XLOOKUP(C2,'IMPORT BASE'!A:A,'IMPORT BASE'!CL:CL)`

but Excel gives an `#VALUE Error` while compiling.

Is there any Proper solution for this to make it as a workable Xlookup?

or If am Missing out anything in this can you please point it out and help me with an solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simply the formula with `INDIRECT`

Option 1: (104 characters)

```
=XLOOKUP(C2,'IMPORT BASE'!A:A,INDIRECT("'IMPORT BASE'!C" & MATCH(AY1,'IMPORT BASE'!$A$1:$DT$1,0),FALSE))
```

Option 2:

```
=XLOOKUP(C2,'IMPORT BASE'!A:A,INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE("'IMPORT BASE'!@:@","@",SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(AY1,'IMPORT BASE'!$A$1:$DT$1,0),4),"1",""))))
```